# Preloading dynamically loaded libraries in linux

Tags: linux, ssl, segmentation-fault, ld, centos6

I have a 7 year old game that a friend built & I have very little of the source code left.
It works perfect on CentOS 4.8 and below, so I'm thinkin' it's a TLS error. I transfered a new folder with all the CentOS 4.8 libraries the program called to the new one... **I'm trying to load the old libraries it called for in ldd specifically to that program,**. This is what I'm trying:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/glibs/ld-linux.so.2 /glibs/libc.so.6 /glibs/libgcc_s.so.1 /glibs/libm.so.6 /glibs/libpthread.so.0 /glibs/libstdc++.so.5 /glibs/libz.so.1 /glibs/libxml2.so.2" /home/g/gameserver
```

I keep getting a **Segmentation Fault** error, does anyone know why? Maybe I don't fully understand what LD_PRELOAD does or something. How would I be able to load old libraries without messing up the originals? **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LD_PRELOAD is more used to override a functionality in a library before the normal ones get used (e.g. custom malloc, socksify all sockets etc). What you probably need is to put all your old libraries into their own directory and then set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it attempts to find the library first in this directory.

Comment: I think this is working I get this error...
    java: relocation error: /glibs/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_out_of_memory, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference
What would that mean?

Comment: I would say that you do not have all old libraries copied into this place. Please check with ldd and make sure that it only needs libraries which are in the directory specified with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and that all of these are taken from the old system.

Comment: Sweet, this worked but I had to downgrade ld-linux.so/ld to a lower version for it to stop giving me the GLIBC_PRIVATE error. Thanks alot for your help! Now just lets hope it doesn't give me errors for other newer programs :)